# validation for min/max on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

i have to validate min/max value in my code on asp.net ...i dont get it ..there are no mistakes as i know, but it doesn't work or i haven't noticed the mistake.I have the code:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" CssClass="genericLabel" Text="Temperatura Corporea (°C): " />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbTemperatura" runat="server" CssClass="smallTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" TargetControlID="tbTemperatura" Mask="99.99" MaskType="Number" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" runat="server" >
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
        <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" ControlExtender="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" ControlToValidate="tbTemperatura" MinimumValue="35" MaximumValue="42" InvalidValueMessage="Temperatura non valida" IsValidEmpty="true" InputDirection="LeftToRight">
         </asp:MaskedEditValidator>
    </td>
</tr
```

Comment: i have use the same code...in odher pages..and it works without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right answer

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Temperatura non valida" 
forecolor="Red" ControlExtender="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" controltovalidate="tbTemperatura" 
minimumvalue="35" maximumvalue="42" 
type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

in need this replacment in MaskedEditValidator

Answer (score 0):

Register the `AjaxControltoolkit` in the top of aspx page 
like

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

here cc1 is used as TagPrefix of the AjaxControlToolKit

use it like `<cc1:MaskedEditExtender >` instead of `<asp:MaskedEditExtender >`

```
<tr>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" CssClass="genericLabel" Text="Temperatura Corporea (°C): " />
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTemperatura" runat="server" CssClass="smallTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:MaskedEditExtender  ID="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" TargetControlID="tbTemperatura" Mask="99.99" MaskType="Number" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" runat="server" >
    </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" ControlExtender="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" ControlToValidate="tbTemperatura" MinimumValue="35" MaximumValue="42" InvalidValueMessage="Temperatura non valida" IsValidEmpty="true" InputDirection="LeftToRight">
     </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
</td>
```

Comment: cc1 what is this  use for>??

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx   I've Updated My answer try now

Comment: look that is just a prefix... first -even if try it will not work... and second is a page is 15500 line of code where at least 10000 has the asp prefix

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx where had you registered the AjaxControlToolKit is it in the web.config or on the aspx page itself ?

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx had you added the reference to the AjaxControlToolKit.dll ?

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx don't mind the cc1 just register the AjaxControlToolKit having TagPrefix='asp'

Comment: <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Temperatura non valida" forecolor="Red" ControlExtender="numberFilterMaskedEditExtender" controltovalidate="tbTemperatura"  minimumvalue="35" maximumvalue="42" type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator> in need this replacment  in MaskedEditValidator

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx when you are doing the validation is it on a submit button ? can you please provide the code of your submit button ?

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx had you used the CausesValidation="false" in the submit button ? if yes make it CausesValidation="true" and try

Comment: @xxxxxxxxxxx if your problem solved please accept my answer so that others can take help from it

Comment: the right is what i have comment :D i mean the comment the has the code.